# how to set set process.env in nextjs according to build or multiple environments

Tags: node.js, reactjs, process, next.js, environment

I am using next js for my project 
i have 3 environments 1 for development and other for staging were i check if it's working okay and other one is production

so i want to change my service fetching urls like

```
in development: "api.development.com"
in staging: "api.staging.com"
in production: "api.production.com"
```

i have seen this url : https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-env-from-next-config-js/next.config.js but in this code

```
// when started in development mode `next dev` or `npm run dev` 
regardless of the value of STAGING environmental variable
const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER
// when `next build` or `npm run build` is used
const isProd = phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD && process.env.STAGING 
!== '1'
// when `next build` or `npm run build` is used
const isStaging = PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD && process.env.STAGING === '1'
```

but in above code i have not understood how he will get

```
process.env.staging = 1
```

for staging build

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `STAGING=1` or `STAGING=0` as an environmental variable before. Syntax for setting it varies for windows, mac and linux.

Alternatively you can also use `.env.local` file for storing env values.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables